# exclude class in testng.xml in selenium webdriver

Tags: web, selenium-webdriver, driver

Hi i am new to testng in selenium web driver..
in my testng.xml 19 classes are there i want to exclude 7 classes or sometime 14classes, is there any proper way to do it?please give some example if possible.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for test selection mechanism, based on certain criteria - let it be package or group. Yes, this can be done with TestNG. Here you have a number of detailed examples:

http://automatictester.co.uk/2014/05/10/selecting-tests-to-be-run-via-testng-xml-file/